# compare in python content of compile_commands.json

Tags: python, compare, snapshot

i want to "freeze" create a snapshot of a compile_commands.json file e.g.

```
[
  {
    "directory": "/home/user/development/project",
    "command": "/usr/bin/c++ ... -c ../foo/foo.cc",
    "file": "../foo/foo.cc"
  },

  ...

  {
    "directory": "/home/user/development/project",
    "command": "/usr/bin/c++ ... -c ../foo/bar.cc",
    "file": "../foo/bar.cc"
  }
]
```

so what interest me are the flags and settings for the compiler in **"command":**. lets say i have:

```
 current compile_commands.json -> create snapshot of commands flags/settings
      
 new compile_commands.json -> compare against current compile_commands.json
```

now the only time the script should report a change is e.g. :

```
 - flag has been removed 
 - new flag has been added
 - content changed e.g. std=c++11 to c++14 or some include beeing modified
```

in case only the positions of the same flags/settings have been changed then nothing shall trigger because the content is still the same just already known flags/settings have been positioned differently. is there a way in python to create such snapshots and then compare and detect only actual content change ?

Answer (score 0):

ok i have found this lib
https://github.com/eggachecat/jycm

this is already what i wanted